# Cognitive Bias, illusory truth effect: its effects on Software Engineers

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias

I have been trying to understand how [illusory truth
effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusory_truth_effect) creates problems for Software Engineers. I have found research on 
the effects of other cognitive biases (e.g. representativeness, availability, etc.) have on Software Development, but none of them mention anything about illusory truth effect.

Does any such research exist? Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. References are encouraged in questions and answers especially when making claims on research etc. I have edited your question with a Wikipedia link to help

Comment: This sounds a bit broad ...

Comment: Yes, the topic is broad, any help or source will be much appreciated.